# URL Encoding Not working : I passed with the layer1 and layer2 parameters. This params is not working correctly

Tags: swift, urlencode

```
var newURL = "https://media.me.com/i/helabojun/MY_Cover_LAKMan_MB_kanjapani_v.43-44?layer1=[text=INCOMING:&fontSize=76&textColor=#ffffff&textAlign=center&anchor=MC&left=50%&top=42%]&layer2=[text=Winter%20days&fontSize=164&textColor=#ffffff&textAlign=center&anchor=MC&left=50%&top=50%]&"
var encodedString = newURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let url = URL(string: encodedString!)
```

It's not passing parameters with the URL.

Can any one give me a help for this?

Comment: You should encode the parameter before, "one per one" instead of the whole string, since each "part" of the URL (scheme, host, etc.) have different encoding. To do so, the clearer method would be to construct the URL with `URLQueryItems`

Comment: Be aware that `URL(string:)` encodes URL strings implicitly if the project is linked to the iOS 17 SDK.

Comment: `URLComponents` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your url, it was slightly incorrect, it was passing "#" with the color, so I encoded it correctly for you (**#** -> **%23**), also removed ":" but if you need it, it is ":" -> "%3A".

So this should work now.

```
var newURL = "https://media.me.com/i/helabojun/MY_Cover_LAKMan_MB_kanjapani_v.43-44?layer1=[text=INCOMING&fontSize=76&textColor=%23ffffff&textAlign=center&anchor=MC&left=50%&top=42%]&layer2=[text=Winter%20days&fontSize=164&textColor=%23ffffff&textAlign=center&anchor=MC&left=50%&top=50%]&"
```

Comment: not working still the same